# How do I select rows that are not recent and are different from the last entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select rows that are not recent and are different from the last entry? We recognize the differences by context field.

My example DB:

```
CREATE TABLE duel (
    id int,
    title varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE try (
    id int,
    duel_id int,
    context varchar(255),
    recent tinyint(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (duel_id) REFERENCES duel(id)
);

INSERT INTO duel (id,title) VALUES (1,"1"),(2,"2"),(3,"3"),(4,"4");
    
INSERT INTO try (id,duel_id,context,recent) VALUES
    (1,1,"a",0),(2,1,"a",0),(3,1,"a",1),(4,2,"a",0),(5,2,"b",0),
    (6,2,"b",1),(7,3,"a",0),(8,3,"a",0),(9,3,"b",1),(10,4,"c",0),
    (11,4,"a",0),(12,4,"c",1);
```

I would like to retrieve from `try table` rows with id: 4, 7, 8 and 11.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM try
WHERE recent != 1 AND (SELECT context FROM try WHERE recent = 1) != context;
```

But I have got the following error:

> ERROR 1242 (21000) at line 120: Subquery returns more than 1 row

I don't know how to deal with it. Maybe there is a solution other than subqueries?

Comment: Could you please explain this part better: "are different from the last entry"? What should this mean? Why should as example the id 1 not be selected?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select rows with `recent=0` and `context <> previous context value` ?

Comment: @JonasMetzler id: 1 is not selected, because it has the same context as id 3.

Comment: @Marleen 1 and 2 are not selected, because they have the same context as id 3, which is recent. 4 is my mistake. Sorry, it should be selected instead of 5.

Comment: @Ahmed recent=0 and context <> context in recent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution for your problem: (For MySQL 5.7)

```
SELECT id,duel_id,context,recent
FROM
(
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN @cntxt = context AND @did = duel_id AND recent = 0 THEN @cur
WHEN @cntxt = context AND @did = duel_id AND recent = 1 THEN (@cur := 1)
WHEN (@cntxt := context) IS NOT NULL AND (@did := duel_id) IS NOT NULL AND (@cur := recent) IS NOT NULL THEN recent
END as flag
FROM try, (SELECT @cur := 0, @cntxt := Null, @did := Null) r
ORDER BY duel_id, context,recent DESC
) as t
WHERE flag = 0
ORDER BY id;
```

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ddcd6782f2f0b130e57aa9703b9a3a34)

Solution for your problem: (For MySQL 8.0+)

```
WITH CT1 AS
(
SELECT *,
SUM(recent) OVER(PARTITION BY duel_id, context ORDER BY recent DESC) as rn
FROM try
)
SELECT id, duel_id, 
context, recent
FROM CT1
WHERE rn = 0
ORDER BY id;
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9691153a0b1052583c7d43c4c06b39f0)

Comment: Thanks, results are good, but unfortunately I have Mysql 5.7.

Comment: @NishantGupta, try to add this record `(13,4,"a",1)`, what results you will get according to your query?

Comment: @nodim I am getting zero record as result.

Comment: @NishantGupta, it works by coincidence, since all the `recent values are =0` for the `context = "a"` and `id in (4,7,8,11)`

Comment: @Ahmed ok so according to you what should be the right result after adding the above record mentioned by you in the previous comment?

Comment: @nodim, it's still confusing, i.e. why rows 1 & 2 should not be in the results set but row 4 should be in?

Comment: @Ahmed, because 1, 2 and 3 have duel_id = 1. 3 is recent with context = "a" and 1 and 2 have context "a". 4, 5 and 6 have duel_id = 2. 6 is recent with context = "b". 5 have context "b", so it cannot be in results and 4 has context "a" (not "b" as 6 with the same duel_id)

Comment: This answer shows exactly the results I want, but unfortunately I don't know how to do it in Mysql 5.7.

Comment: @nodim so do you want partition over duel_id as well?

Comment: @NishantGupta yes

Comment: @nodim what will be the result if I add a record(i.e. (13,4,"c",0))?

Comment: 4, 7, 8 and 11.  13 will be skip because it has the same context as 12, which is recent.

Comment: But if you add (14,4,"b",0) then it should be in results, because has other context than 12.

Comment: @nodim Try my solution now i updated it.

Comment: I cannot upvote now, because I have only 13 reputation points

Comment: Surely this is much more complex than necessary

Comment: @RobSpoor if you see when I gave the answer, the question was not much cleared. You can see and understand from the above comments that question gets cleared slowly with more comments and more counter questions asked from the user. When the requirement got cleared other user(@Marleen) gave the simplified answer which I also thought about but if I updated my answer with the simplified one, other users would have definitely downvoted my answer on the basis of Plagiarism. (Also, I am ready to delete my answer but it gets accepted by the user and I am unable to delete it)

Comment: @nodim can you please reject my answer so, I can delete it?